# In array of nested object how to access previous object value and increment an fileld

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two array of object

1. WALLETS

```
      wallets = [
          { title: "Wallet 1", _id: "1", created: new Date("2020-07-14T00:00:00.000Z") },
          { title: "Wallet 2", _id: "2", created: new Date("2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z") },
          { title: "Wallet 3", _id: "3", created: new Date("2020-07-19T00:00:00.000Z") }]
```

2. Transactions

```
    tcode = [
      { "createdOn": "2020-03-16T11:58:52.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 2, "amount": 212.92, walletId: 1 },
      { "createdOn": "2020-01-01T15:21:58.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 3, "amount": 624.22, walletId: 2 },
      { "createdOn": "2019-12-13T20:50:38.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 4, "amount": -874.15, walletId: 3 },
      { "createdOn": "2020-05-25T22:37:20.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 5, "amount": -502.68, walletId: 1 },
      { "createdOn": "2020-01-24T10:33:27.000Z", "type": "Debit", "_id": 6, "amount": 897.46, walletId: 2 },
      { "createdOn": "2019-09-24T00:45:15.000Z", "type": "Debit", "_id": 7, "amount": 981.36, walletId: 1 },
      { "createdOn": "2019-12-06T22:17:35.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 8, "amount": -934.81, walletId: 2 },
      { "createdOn": "2019-09-06T03:49:31.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 9, "amount": 818.77, walletId: 3 },
      { "createdOn": "2020-04-23T22:09:46.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 10, "amount": 312.33, walletId: 3 },
      { "createdOn": "2020-07-18T09:15:12.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 11, "amount": -739.77, walletId: 1 }
    ]
```

Now I am looping through the wallets filtering the objects and sort them ascending order using

```
for (let i in wallets){
  temp = tcode.filter(data => data.walletId == wallets[i]._id).sort(((a, b) => { return new Date(b.createdOn) - new Date(a.createdOn) })).map(data=> ({
    _id: data._id,
    credit:data.type=='Credit'? data.amount:null,
    debit:data.type=='Debit'? data.amount:null,
    amount:data.amount,
    createdOn:data.createdOn,
    type:data.type,
    walletId:data.walletId,
  }))
 }
```

Now i needed to add the Opening Balance in each newly mapped object which is addition of all the previous amount from each object, Using Simple For loop i Can active this but is there a better way to do this using Reduce and Map?

Desired Result:

```
[
  {
    _id: 6,
    credit: null,
    debit: 897.46,
    amount: 897.46,
    createdOn: '2020-01-24T10:33:27.000Z',
    type: 'Debit',
    walletId: 2,
    openingBalance: 897.46
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    credit: 624.22,
    debit: null,
    amount: 624.22,
    createdOn: '2020-01-01T15:21:58.000Z',
    type: 'Credit',
    walletId: 2,
    openingBalance: 1521.68
  },
  {
    _id: 8,
    credit: -934.81,
    debit: null,
    amount: -934.81,
    createdOn: '2019-12-06T22:17:35.000Z',
    type: 'Credit',
    walletId: 2,
    openingBalance: 586.87
  }
]
```

Comment: This is precisely what `reduce` is for, since each iteration receives the result of the previous iteration.

Comment: Can you add the expected result? What do you need the final array to look like?

Comment: what is the filter criteria, somehow the code provided doesn t match the criteria..

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for reply. see i Needed the Opening Balance field in every object inside of array, I have updated the question with desired output.

Comment: @EugenSunic the filter create three different array with matching walletId

Comment: @SakoBu i have updated the question with desired output

Comment: In the desired result, isn't it strange that the "openBalance" of the most recent transaction is the same as the amount of that transaction? Shouldn't it be that this is the case for the *oldest* transaction? Aren't you summing in the wrong direction?

Comment: @trincot indeed you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to produce an array of wallet-like objects, which each have a `transactions` property, having the array that you describe.

Note however that the `openBalance` should sum up in the opposite direction, i.e. from the older transaction to the most recent transaction.

I would also perform a sort operation only once, and then use a `Map` to collect the data in the right wallet's `transaction` list.

Here is code you could use. As a bonus it also registers the current balance at the level of the extended wallet object:

```js
let wallets = [{ title: "Wallet 1", _id: "1", created: new Date("2020-07-14T00:00:00.000Z") },{ title: "Wallet 2", _id: "2", created: new Date("2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z") },{ title: "Wallet 3", _id: "3", created: new Date("2020-07-19T00:00:00.000Z") }]
let tcode = [{ "createdOn": "2020-03-16T11:58:52.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 2, "amount": 212.92, walletId: 1 },{ "createdOn": "2020-01-01T15:21:58.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 3, "amount": 624.22, walletId: 2 },{ "createdOn": "2019-12-13T20:50:38.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 4, "amount": -874.15, walletId: 3 },{ "createdOn": "2020-05-25T22:37:20.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 5, "amount": -502.68, walletId: 1 },{ "createdOn": "2020-01-24T10:33:27.000Z", "type": "Debit", "_id": 6, "amount": 897.46, walletId: 2 },{ "createdOn": "2019-09-24T00:45:15.000Z", "type": "Debit", "_id": 7, "amount": 981.36, walletId: 1 },{ "createdOn": "2019-12-06T22:17:35.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 8, "amount": -934.81, walletId: 2 },{ "createdOn": "2019-09-06T03:49:31.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 9, "amount": 818.77, walletId: 3 },{ "createdOn": "2020-04-23T22:09:46.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 10, "amount": 312.33, walletId: 3 },{ "createdOn": "2020-07-18T09:15:12.000Z", "type": "Credit", "_id": 11, "amount": -739.77, walletId: 1 }];

// Key the wallets by their id, and add a list of transactions for them
let map = new Map(wallets.map(wallet => [+wallet._id, ({...wallet, ...{ transactions: [], openBalance: 0 }})]));
// Get a sorted copy of the transactions
let sorted = [...tcode].sort((a, b) =>  a.createdOn.localeCompare(b.createdOn));
// Put each transaction in the corresponding wallet's list
for (let { createdOn, type, _id, amount, walletId } of sorted) {
    let wallet = map.get(+walletId); // pick up the corresponding wallet
    // Avoid floating point inaccuracies
    wallet.openBalance = +(wallet.openBalance + amount).toFixed(2); 
    wallet.transactions.unshift({
        _id, 
        credit: type == "Credit" ? amount : null,
        debit: type == "Dedit" ? amount : null,
        amount,
        createdOn, 
        type, 
        walletId, 
        openBalance: wallet.openBalance
    });
}
// Extract the result from the map
let richWallets = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(richWallets);
```

The above also solves a potential issue with floating point precision issues when adding fractional amounts.

By lack of a proper decimal type in JavaScript, it is actually good practice to store amounts as cents, so they are always integers. Then leave the presentation in proper currency to the presentation layer, which would divide the amount by 100.

Comment: Thanks for help, it is running as expected in js but in typescript i am facing some error ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'transactions' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'walletId' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify

Comment: You must have done something different, as there is no circular reference in the output of the snippet here. The error seems to indicate that you have assigned an object to `walletId`. That property should not change to anything else than it was: a number. I can only guess, but maybe you wrote `=` where `==` was intended?

Comment: I messed up by assigning it to type any. Now it is working properly.Thanks again for help

Comment: I have another issue now can you please help.                                                     error TS2345: Argument of type '(number | { transactions: any[]; openBalance: number; id: string; walletTitle: string; openingBalance: Number; })[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<[{}, {}]>'.
  Type '(number | { transactions: any[]; openBalance: number; id: string; walletTitle: string; openingBalance: Number; })[]' is missing the following properties from type '[{}, {}]': 0, 1

Comment: Well, that is a typescript question really. The context of this error is of course important. Which line? But really, if you have a question that relates to type checking in typescript, that goes beyond this current question. If you cannot solve it, then just ask a new question, and tag it also with `typescript`.

Comment: this line let map = new Map(wallets.map(wallet => [+wallet._id, ({...wallet, ...{ transactions: [], openBalance: 0 }})]));

Comment: I don't know too much how to fix such typescript errors. But you can rewrite this as follows: `let map = new Map;` and then `for (let wallet of wallets) { map.set(+wallet.id, {...wallet, ...{transactions: [], openBalance: 0}}); }`. Possibly that will work better.

Answer (score 0):

You could first used reduce group your arrays by keys which are walletIds, then extract those values/arrays and sort each one of them separately by date

```js
const wallets = [{
    title: "Wallet 1",
    _id: "1",
    created: new Date("2020-07-14T00:00:00.000Z")
  },
  {
    title: "Wallet 2",
    _id: "2",
    created: new Date("2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z")
  },
  {
    title: "Wallet 3",
    _id: "3",
    created: new Date("2020-07-19T00:00:00.000Z")
  }
]

const tcode = [{
    "createdOn": "2020-03-16T11:58:52.000Z",
    "type": "Credit",
    "_id": 2,
    "amount": 212.92,
    walletId: 1
  },
  {
    "createdOn": "2020-01-01T15:21:58.000Z",
    "type": "Credit",
    "_id": 3,
    "amount": 624.22,
    walletId: 2
  },
  {
    "createdOn": "2019-12-13T20:50:38.000Z",
    "type": "Credit",
    "_id": 4,
    "amount": -874.15,
    walletId: 3
  },
  {
    "createdOn": "2020-05-25T22:37:20.000Z",
    "type": "Credit",
    "_id": 5,
    "amount": -502.68,
    walletId: 1
  },
  {
    "createdOn": "2020-01-24T10:33:27.000Z",
    "type": "Debit",
    "_id": 6,
    "amount": 897.46,
    walletId: 2
  },
  {
    "createdOn": "2019-09-24T00:45:15.000Z",
    "type": "Debit",
    "_id": 7,
    "amount": 981.36,
    walletId: 1
  },
  {
    "createdOn": "2019-12-06T22:17:35.000Z",
    "type": "Credit",
    "_id": 8,
    "amount": -934.81,
    walletId: 2
  },
  {
    "createdOn": "2019-09-06T03:49:31.000Z",
    "type": "Credit",
    "_id": 9,
    "amount": 818.77,
    walletId: 3
  },
  {
    "createdOn": "2020-04-23T22:09:46.000Z",
    "type": "Credit",
    "_id": 10,
    "amount": 312.33,
    walletId: 3
  },
  {
    "createdOn": "2020-07-18T09:15:12.000Z",
    "type": "Credit",
    "_id": 11,
    "amount": -739.77,
    walletId: 1
  }
]


const groupedArr = tcode.reduce((acc, x) => {
      const match = wallets.some(y => y._id.toString() === x.walletId.toString())
      const key = x.walletId
        if (!match) return acc;
        if (acc[key]) {
            const lastIndex = acc[key].length - 1;
            acc[key].push({ ...x,
              openingBalance: acc[key][lastIndex].openingBalance + x.amount
            });
          } else {
            acc[key] = [{ ...x,
              openingBalance: x.amount
            }];
          }
          return acc;

        }, {})
      const sortedArr = Object.values(groupedArr).map(x => x.sort(((a, b) => {
        return new Date(b.createdOn) - new Date(a.createdOn)
      })))

      console.log(sortedArr)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i needed the OpeningBalance field in every object inside the array which will be incremented value of amounts

Comment: @RedBaron check the answer again

Comment: it seems working but Needed to Sort first i guess because the opening balance doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks and appreciated your valuable help

Comment: we needed to sort first otherwise the opening balance doesn't make sense ,this approach i have tried previously but it doesn't solve the problem